# Changing color for each stacked bar in D3.js

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

can someone help me with changing the color of the stacked bar in d3? if have tried some method, but it doesn't work. Thank You.

example :

1. admit_male - light blue
2. admit_female - deep blue
3. reject_male - pale red
4. reject_female - deep red

var data = [
{
Category: "University Of Bath",
admit_male: 512,
admit_female: 89,
reject_male: 313,
reject_female: 19

```
  },
  {
    Category: "University Of Bristol",
    admit_male: 22,
    admit_female: 24,
    reject_male: 351,
    reject_female: 317
  },
  {
    Category: "University Of Greenwish",
    admit_male: 138,
    admit_female: 131,
    reject_male: 279,
    reject_female: 244
  },

];

var w=500,h=600,padding=40;
var svg=d3.select('body').append('svg')
            .attr('width', w)
            .attr('height', h);
var stack=d3.stack()
            .keys(['admit_male','admit_female','reject_male','reject_female']);

var datasets=[d3.stack().keys(['admit_male','admit_female'])(data),
              d3.stack().keys(['reject_male','reject_female'])(data)];

var num_groups=datasets.length;

var xlabels=data.map(function(d){return d['Category']});

var xscale=d3.scaleBand()
                .domain(xlabels)
                .range([padding,w-padding])
                .paddingInner(0.5);

var ydomain_min=d3.min(datasets.flat().map(function(row) {
                        return d3.min(row.map(function(d){return d[1];}));
                    }));
var ydomain_max=d3.max(datasets.flat().map(function(row) {
                        return d3.max(row.map(function(d){return d[1];}));
                    }));

var yscale=d3.scaleLinear()
                .domain([0,ydomain_max])
                .range([h-padding,padding]);

var accent = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeBlues[6]);
var xaxis=d3.axisBottom(xscale);
var yaxis=d3.axisLeft(yscale);

d3.range(num_groups).forEach(function(gnum) {
    svg.selectAll('g.group'+gnum)
        .data(datasets[gnum])
        .enter()
        .append('g')
            .attr('fill',accent)
            .attr('class', 'group'+gnum)
        .selectAll('rect')
        .data(d=>d)
        .enter()
        .append('rect')
            .attr('x',(d,i)=>xscale(xlabels[i])+(xscale.bandwidth()/num_groups)*gnum)
            .attr('y',d=>yscale(d[1]))
            .attr('width',xscale.bandwidth()/num_groups)
            .attr('height',d=>yscale(d[0])-yscale(d[1]));
        });

svg.append('g')
        .attr('class','axis x')
        .attr('transform','translate(0,'+(h-padding)+")")
    .call(xaxis);
svg.append('g')
        .attr('class','axis y')
        .attr('transform','translate('+padding+",0)")
        
    .call(yaxis);
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an ordinal scale for the colors:

```
const colorScale = d3.scaleOrdinal()
    .domain(['admit_male', 'admit_female', 'reject_male', 'reject_female'])
    .range(['#a4c5fd', '#4472b4', '#f36e92', '#b02d51']);
```

And call it using the `key` property:

```
.attr('fill', d=>colorScale(d.key))
```

Here is the demo:

```js
var data = [{
    Category: "University Of Bath",
    admit_male: 512,
    admit_female: 89,
    reject_male: 313,
    reject_female: 19

  },
  {
    Category: "University Of Bristol",
    admit_male: 22,
    admit_female: 24,
    reject_male: 351,
    reject_female: 317
  },
  {
    Category: "University Of Greenwish",
    admit_male: 138,
    admit_female: 131,
    reject_male: 279,
    reject_female: 244
  },

];

var w = 500,
  h = 600,
  padding = 40;
var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
  .attr('width', w)
  .attr('height', h);
var stack = d3.stack()
  .keys(['admit_male', 'admit_female', 'reject_male', 'reject_female']);
  
  const colorScale = d3.scaleOrdinal()
    .domain(['admit_male', 'admit_female', 'reject_male', 'reject_female'])
    .range(['#a4c5fd', '#4472b4', '#f36e92', '#b02d51']);

var datasets = [d3.stack().keys(['admit_male', 'admit_female'])(data),
  d3.stack().keys(['reject_male', 'reject_female'])(data)
];

var num_groups = datasets.length;

var xlabels = data.map(function(d) {
  return d['Category']
});

var xscale = d3.scaleBand()
  .domain(xlabels)
  .range([padding, w - padding])
  .paddingInner(0.5);

var ydomain_min = d3.min(datasets.flat().map(function(row) {
  return d3.min(row.map(function(d) {
    return d[1];
  }));
}));
var ydomain_max = d3.max(datasets.flat().map(function(row) {
  return d3.max(row.map(function(d) {
    return d[1];
  }));
}));

var yscale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, ydomain_max])
  .range([h - padding, padding]);

var accent = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeBlues[6]);
var xaxis = d3.axisBottom(xscale);
var yaxis = d3.axisLeft(yscale);

d3.range(num_groups).forEach(function(gnum) {
  svg.selectAll('g.group' + gnum)
    .data(datasets[gnum])
    .enter()
    .append('g')
    .attr('fill', d=>colorScale(d.key))
    .attr('class', 'group' + gnum)
    .selectAll('rect')
    .data(d => d)
    .enter()
    .append('rect')
    .attr('x', (d, i) => xscale(xlabels[i]) + (xscale.bandwidth() / num_groups) * gnum)
    .attr('y', d => yscale(d[1]))
    .attr('width', xscale.bandwidth() / num_groups)
    .attr('height', d => yscale(d[0]) - yscale(d[1]));
});

svg.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'axis x')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + (h - padding) + ")")
  .call(xaxis);
svg.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'axis y')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(' + padding + ",0)")

  .call(yaxis);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thankss for helping